# If $\binom{n-1}{r} = (k^2-3)\cdot \binom{n}{r+1}$. Then values of $k\in

Tags: combinatorics

If $\displaystyle \binom{n-1}{r}  = (k^2-3)\cdot \binom{n}{r+1}$ and $k\in {\mathbb{R}}$. Then values of $k\in $

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write it as

$\displaystyle \frac{(n-1)!}{r!\cdot (n-1-r)!} = (k^2-3)\cdot \frac{n!}{(r+1)!\cdot (n-r-1)!} = (k^2-3)\frac{n(n-1)!}{(r+1)\cdot r!\cdot (n-r-1)!}$

So we get $\displaystyle (k^2-3)\cdot \frac{n}{r+1}=1\Rightarrow (k^2-3) = \frac{r+1}{n}.$

Now Here we Using The fact $\displaystyle (n-1)\geq r\Rightarrow n\geq (r+1)\Rightarrow \frac{r+1}{n}\leq 1$

So $\displaystyle (k^2-3)\leq 1\Rightarrow (k-2)\cdot (k+2)\leq 0\Rightarrow k\in \left[-2,2\right]$, But my answer is not match,

How can i find more close answer, Help me

Thanks

Comment: from $(k^2-3)=r+1/n$ you get also $k^2-3 \geq 1/n$ (since $r\geq 0$)

Comment: Perhaps an application of Pascal's rule?

Comment: How precise shall the answer be? The conclusion $|k|\le 2$ is certainly correct. One could add that $k$ must be algebraic, in fact at most a quadratic irrational, more precisely the square root of a rational. And of course $|k|>\sqrt 3$ as per Milly's comment

Comment: Thanks Milly,  Sherlock Holmes and  Hagen von Eitzen.Got it.